React-Native and Supabase with Google-Auth not working for me
I tried setting up Google authentication with SupaBase using React Native following these steps here. However, I encountered a DEVELOPER_ERROR with code 10, indicating a SHA-1 error.
I use npx expo run:android for running build
-I tried using ./gradlew signingReport giving me same debug and production sha-1
-I tried eas credentials both for development and production which is different from the key from gradle
-I tried key from keytool -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
here is my app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "rent",
    "slug": "rent",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.rentway.rentway"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.rentway.rentway"
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "output": "static",
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      [
        "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin",
        {
          "iosUrlScheme": "com.googleusercontent.apps._some_id_here_"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      },
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  }
}

here is my eas.json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 10.0.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

here is the function
// utils/googleLogin.ts

import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';
import { GoogleSignin, statusCodes } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
import { supabase } from '@/utils/supaBase';

GoogleSignin.configure({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'],
    webClientId: "xxxx",
});

export const handleGoogleLogin = async (setLoading: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>): Promise<void> => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
        await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
        const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
        if (userInfo.idToken) {
            const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithIdToken({
                provider: 'google',
                token: userInfo.idToken,
            });
            console.log(error, data);
        } else {
            throw new Error('No ID token present!');
        }
    } catch (error: any) {
        if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
            console.log('User cancelled the login flow');
        } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
            console.log('Operation (e.g. sign in) is in progress already');
        } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
            console.log('Play services not available or outdated');
        } else {
            console.error('Some other error happened', error.message, error.code);
        }
    } finally {
        setLoading(false);
    }
};

xxxx is replaced by private ids
